# primes and logarithms [theory]

Tags: math, theory

I know this is not a mathematical forum but given the bright minds that participate here, i am sure that this question is of interest nevertheless. How would you develop and explain the following statement:

> "we can convert the product of a set
>   of primes into a sum of the logarithms
>   of the primes by applying logarithms
>   to both parts of this conjecture"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`log(a * b) = log(a) + log(b)`

Comment: Thanks Orange Dog. so it simply means log(2x3x5x7)=log(2)+log(3)+log(5)+log(7). What is the benefit of bringing in logarithms into this situation?

Comment: @Baba - No idea. Presumably wherever you got that statement from would explain that.

Comment: @Baba - there's no benefit in this specific case, but frequently operations are done in the log domain to prevent overflow.  e.g. if you want `a/b`, but both `a` and `b` have huge magnitudes, you can calculate `exp((log(a)-log(b))`, which shouldn't give problems.  See http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/float_point.aspx for more.

Comment: The application I'm familiar with - quadratic sieve - makes use of floating point (logarithms) instead of big integers for the reduction in storage and execution time. A particular algorithm question would be more likely on topic than the algebra question you originally posed :-)

Answer (score 1):

thanks for that OrangeDog and John!

re benefit of introducing logs, OrangeDog is right indeed. It is specific to an exercise from an MIT OpenCourse class. Here's the full details:

> There is a cute result from number
>   theory that states that for
>   sufficiently large n the product of
>   the primes less than n is less than or
>   equal to e^n and that as n grows,
>   this becomes a tight bound (that is,
>   the ratio of the product of the primes
>   to e^n gets close to 1 as n grows).
>
> Computing a product of a large number
>   of prime numbers can result in a very
>   large number, which can potentially
>   cause problems with our computation.
>   [note: this is what John was referring
>   to] So we can convert the product of a
>   set of primes into a sum of the
>   logarithms of the primes by applying
>   logarithms to both parts of this
>   conjecture.  In this case, the
>   conjecture above reduces to the claim
>   that the sum of the logarithms of all
>   the primes less than n is less than n,
>   and that as n grows, the ratio of this
>   sum to n gets close to 1.

**EDIT**

given these statements i am, however, unsure about how to apply them i.e.

how do we go from here:

2 x 3 x 5 <= e^7

to

> "applying
>   logarithms to both parts of this
>   conjecture."

**EDIT 2**

got it...

2 x 3 x 5 <= e^7

knowing that logarithms are the opposite of powers we can say:

log(2x3x5) <= 7

which is also the same as:

log(2)+log(3)+log(5) <= 7

this only starts to show its "value" when n (in this case 7) gets larger i.e. the 1000th prime or higher

Comment: log(2) + log(3) + log(5) <= 7